# Seg fault on my own version of getline

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, getline, realloc

I'm trying to make a simple version of getline. It should read a line in from stdin, reallocating the size of the buffer as necessary. It should also return the number of characters read. It takes a char ** so that the reallocated buffer can be later freed. Why am I getting a segfault?

Heres my version:

```
int get_input_line(char **buff, int start_size) {
char c;
int stop = 0, length = 0, k = start_size;
while(!stop) {
    if(length > k) {
        k += 50;
        buff = (char *)(realloc(buff, start_size + 1));
    }
    c = getchar();
    if(c == '\n'){
        stop = 1;
    }
    buff[length] = c; 
    length++;
}
return length;
}
```

And here's the call:

```
char *buff = (char *)(malloc(50 + 1));
get_input_line(&buff, 50);
printf("%s", buff);
```

Comment: It's not answering the question, but you're also not checking the return value of either malloc or realloc. If either of those return NULL, you'll quite possibly end up with a crash at runtime for referencing null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not detecting EOF reliably.  You need to save the result of `getchar()` in an `int` and not a `char`.  And you should not try to store `EOF` in your buffer.

You're not checking your memory allocations.

You're not null terminating the output string, so the `printf()` in `main()` may crash.

You're confusing someone (maybe me, maybe the compiler, maybe yourself) by allocating 51 bytes and telling the function that it only has 50 bytes to play with.

And, most particularly, **you need to be using `*buff` at most points inside the function**, including, in particular, when adding a character:

```
(*buff)[length++] = c;
```

You really should be paying more attention to all those compiler warnings.  If your compiler isn't giving you any, get a better compiler (or turn on the warning flags - but you should be being shrieked at by the compiler in its default mode).

Also, you are miscalling `realloc()` on three grounds.  One is the `*buff` issue.  The second is that you want the size to be `k`, not `start_size + 1`.  The other is that you are assigning the result to the input parameter.  This is a 'no-no' because if the allocation fails, you've lost your pointer to the previously (and still) allocated data.  Always use the idiom:

```
void *new_data = realloc(old_data, new_size);
if (new_data == 0)
    ...deal with out of memory error...
else
{
    old_data = new_data;
    old_size = new_size;
}
```

Applied to your code, that means:

```
char *new_buff = (char *)realloc(*buff, k); // NOT start_size+1!!!
if (new_buff == 0)
    ...deal with out of memory error...
else
    *buff = new_buff;
```

There are those who argue against the cast on `malloc()` and `realloc()` and `calloc()`; there are those who prefer the casts present.  There are arguments on both sides, of differing degrees of validity.  I prefer the cast - I respect those who prefer no cast.  We reach our different conclusions for different reasons.

I have not studied the code for other 'off-by-one' errors.  I suspect that there may be several of those, too.

Comment: why do you prefer to cast? except for C++ compatibility, I cannot see any good reason.

Comment: I reckon my C code is compilable with a C++ compiler, so it is precisely for C++ compatibility.  That's my self-imposed requirement; if you don't have that as a requirement, don't include the cast.

Answer (score 6):

You probably meant:

```
*buff = (realloc(*buff, new_size));
^                ^
```

And

```
(*buff)[length] = c;
```

You're also missing the 0 terminator.

#### EDIT

As `nos` points out, `length > k` should be `length >= k` .

Comment: And `length > k` should be `length >= k`

Comment: And the allocated size should be `k` or `k+1` and not `start_size+1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yup, the list of problems goes on and on (char getchar etc). Your post does a way better job listing all the issues :-)

Comment: @cnicutar Can you please update your answer (even a space somewhere should suffice)? I was checking SO from my ipad and it somehow ended up down voting your good answer. I can't seem to cancel my down vote since it is now locked and it wants the answer to be updated. My sincere apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
buff = (char *)(realloc(buff, start_size + 1));
```

should be

```
*buff = (char *)(realloc(*buff, k + 1));
```

Also

```
buf[length] = c
```

should be

```
*buf[length] = c
```

Moreover, I think you forgot to store a final `'\0'`.